# Не могу понять, что значит избежать блокировок БД

Tags: php, laravel, backend

дали тестовое задание на стеке PHP 7.*, Laravel 8. копипастить тз я не буду, но задание это сделать сайт "статейник" с парой страниц

- Главная
- Каталог статей
- Страница статьи

статью можно лайкать, при открытии статьи через 5 секунд отправляется запрос который инкрементирует счетчик просмотров статьи. и в тестовом в конце есть такой пункт

> При реализации API методов учтите, что онлайн блога заранее не
> известен. Ваша реализация должна позволять избежать блокировок БД в
> случае огромного количества входящих запросов (допустим 1 млн входящих
> запрос на инкрементацию счетчика просмотров). Это требования
> необходимо вам для организации правильного хранения лайков и
> просмотров.

я гуглил. нагуглил только то что "блокировка бд" это транзакции... и почитал статьи о оптимизации запросов на Laravel, но мне кажется это не то что мне нужно. ну и вот с связи с этим у меня вопросы с которыми я не могу разобраться сам

1. Что такое блокировка БД от большого количества запросов?
2. Как избежать этой самой блокировки?
3. Есть ли решения для этой проблемы в Laravel?

Comment: `онлайн блога заранее не известен` - "преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол. Только одни затраты, и никакой пользы" (Кнут). Зачем делать механизм, который может не потребоваться? Самая простая реализация счетчика выдержит минимум 20 rps. `1 млн входящих запрос на инкрементацию счетчика просмотров` - и встречный вопрос - а сервер сможет **показать** статью при 1M rps? Думаю, на этом серваке должен быть включен кеш Nginx + 64 ядра CPU - тогда справится.

Comment: `требования необходимо вам для организации правильного хранения` - ну ок. Тогда делается таблица "статья,ip-кто-лайнул,дата-время". Запрос => очередь => демон (пишет порциями, а заодно обновляет кеш счетчика просмотров). 1 млн - это много. Возможно потребуется организация кластера. А это уже DevOps. С одной стороны задача простая - сделать простенький блог. А с другой - прилепили 1М rps. Странно как-то. Как решится вопрос с тестовым, напишите, что там имелось в виду, какое решение они ждали. Будет интересно почитать.

Comment: @TotalPusher, счётчик просмотров, а не лайков. Лайки именные, надо запрещать повторную установку и, возможно, разрешать снятие. А вот просмотры - это просто увеличивающееся число, один и тот же пользователь может смотреть несколько раз.

Comment: @Qwertiy, лайки я взял из вопроса: `хранения лайков и просмотров`, то есть постановщик задачи это связал. А связал, возможно, потому что дальше будет задача "не делать +1 при нажатии F5"

Comment: @TotalPusher, хм.. Да, упоминаются, но требования на миллион запросов вроде к ним не относятся. F5 может решаться кукой с коротким временем жизни. Теоретически может быть ситуация, что пользователь столько статей наоткрывает, что превысит размер кук, но мне она кажется маловероятной. И вообще, разве тестовые задания предполагают, что к ним будет "следующее задание"?

Comment: @Qwertiy я бы сделал с кеширующим слоем, как вы ниже написали. У меня вопрос к трактовке задания, в этом случае правильно было бы уточнить эти детали у постановщика. `F5 может решаться кукой` да, может. Но тут `При реализации API`, то есть должно решаться на стороне API. `разве тестовые задания предполагают, что к ним будет "следующее задание"` - а это как раз вопрос с подковыркой, насколько далеко мыслит тот, кто делает. Или весь код пойдет на свалку, в случае простого кеширования. Я при собесе так и делаю - вот задача, опишите как будете решать. А вот новое требование. Хорошо, а вот вам еще

Comment: @TotalPusher, ну описать - это одно, а добавлять требования к готовому тестовому - это другое. Что касается счётчика просмотров: тут изначально 2 варианта - считать при открытии страницы (поэтому я предложил куку) или считать отдельным ajax-запросом (можно использовать sessionStorage или localStorage и не слать повторный запрос). Поскольку информация о просмотрах некритичная (и её в любом случае можно накручивать: делать проверку на ip нельзя, потоуму что у провайдеров до сих пор NAT популярен, а без этого решается приватным окном), то не вижу смысла в дополнительной валидации на бэке.

Comment: @TotalPusher, ещё есть вариант считать просмотры только зарегистрированными пользователями, но мне кажется, что просмотры так никто не считает. Так что если рассчёт на это, то скорее надо было ставить задачу оптимизировать лайки, а не просмотры.

Comment: @TotalPusher в общем. не раскрыл свой ответ их лид к сожалению. я так понимаю потому что я принял другое предложение и не стал продолжать сотрудничество. но докопался таки и вот хоть что то, что я получил в переписке: "Если направить в БД 1кк запросов на запись, то при ограниченных настройках сервера, БД ляжет. Нужно придумать способ не напрямую записывать и читать запросы из БД" и "Я на вопрос уже ответил, что хотел бы видеть работу с кэшем. Логику в рамках тестового не готов обсуждать) Redis - это просто драйвер, можно хоть в файлах кеш хранить. Для ларавель переключить драйвер не проблема"

Answer (score 2):

Возможно имеется в виду, что нужен какой-то слой кэширования.

Например, держим счётчик в памяти, а в БД сохраняем не чаще раза в секунду.

Ну и при чтение достаём аналогично: если есть в памяти, берём оттуда, если нет, то считываем из базы и кэшируем.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. а адекватно ли будет решать такую проблему очередями?

Comment: Я только сделал предположение. Понятия не имею, какие инструменты для этого предназначены в php и laravel. Очереди могут быть не совсем в тему, т. к. я предлагаю из множества однотипных запросов на апдейт счётчика выкидывать промежуточнеы апдейты - не знаю, умеет ли так очередь. Может надо вообще редис прикрутить...

Comment: очередь засунуть в redis для быстрого доступа к задачам. API запрос будет приходить в метод который добавляет задачу в очередь. а в хэндле задачи будет код для инкремента лайка. таким образом каждый 
 поставленный на клиенте лайк будет создавать новую задачу в очереди для инкремента, ну и демон соответственно будет потом эти задачи выполнять. что думаете? ...хотя 1кк запросов хмм

Comment: @midnightelf18, а зачем?

Comment: потому что я не знаю как иначе поставить "ограничитель" в одну секунду на запись в бд

Comment: @midnightelf18, [`throttle`](https://doka.guide/js/throttle/).